# creating gui overlay interface in game

Tags: user-interface, interface

I've created a relatively simple tower defense game using c++ and SFML.  I'm very interested in creating a nice gui overlay for it, ie hud, menus, etc.  I know there are a lot of gui libraries out there, but I would like to make my own (for learning purposes.

I'm very familiar with working with graphics, but I'm not as familiar with GUI systems (I just render my frames, and don't worry about widgets, title bars, etc.).

Are there any good articles out there, or perhaps suggestions anyone has regarding how to layout such an interface?

Comment: I need a clarification, as to what you mean by "layout," in this context.  Are you looking for advice on UI-design best-practices (regarding usability, clarity, etc.?), or are you looking for advice on how to structure your homegrown UI API?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways I know of (at least for Java) to get a nice HUD in your game.  One method is to have a separate 3D world with the UI elements placed directly in front of the camera, then overlay that camera's view over the main view.  This can be buggy at times, especially when you don't have a good color filter, or when you have a high number of objects being displayed.  Another method is to look at a GUI library designed for this purpose (such as NiftyGUI for Java).

A quick Google search lead me to [a listing on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_platform-independent_GUI_libraries) of many open-source GUI libraries you could use.  There are many others out there, so you should probably do the Google search yourself, or look around on [GitHub](https://github.com/) and [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/).